# In scala, is a unary_ a method or a property?

Tags: scala, operator-keyword, prefix, unary-operator

Since the following are equivalent:

`-2
2.unary_-`

and since parentheses are optional for methods with no arguments, shouldn't

`2.unary_-()`

also evaluate to `-2` ? Instead, I get:

`error: Int does not take parameters`

The book I'm working through says that `unary_-` is a method, though this error seems to suggest it is a property of Int. Is this correct?

Comment: Apparently there is a distinction between functions with no parameters and functions with an empty parameter list, see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3081.html). Functions with no parameters are accessed like a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceeding from evan058's advice, I decided to run an experiement:

```
class Myint1(n:Int) {
    def unary_-() = -n /* method definition has parentheses */
}

class Myint2(n: Int) {
    def unary_- = -n /* no parentheses in definition */
}
val n1 = new Myint1(3)
val n2 = new Myint2(3)

n1.unary_- /* prints -3 */
n2.unary_- /* also gives -3 */

n1.unary_-() /* prints -3 */
n2.unary_-() /* throws error: Int does not take parameters */
```

So `unary_-` is a method, not a property. The reason for the behavior is that there is a difference between a method definition with parentheses and without. Note that, expectedly, `-n1` and `-n2` both result in `-3`.

Comment: if method is defined with parenthesis you can omit them or not. If it is defined without them, you can't put them.

Comment: Yeah, That's the behavior I was trying to demonstrate. An interesting exception to this rule is that if your method is an `override` of a method defined with parenthesis, you can omit them in your definition, but it will still compile as if you included them.

Comment: BTW: there are no properties, conceptually. A `val` is just a getter method (i.e. a method with no parameter list), a `var` is just a setter (i.e. a method named `foo_=` with one parameter list with one parameter) / getter pair. The compiler will only actually *generate* those methods if it needs to and otherwise compile them into JVM fields, but *conceptually*, there is no difference between a method with no parameter list and a `val`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag is that why you can also do `val unary_- = -n` and get the same behavior? I noticed that while I was messing around in the REPL, but just didn't think anything of it.